# Data processed in Flink is not saved in the Cassandra database

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, cassandra, stream, apache-flink

I'm implementing the application that fetches data from external environments via Apache Kafka.
This data is first mapped to objects and then passed to the process (TimeWindow) (look at the code below)

```
val busDataStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
  .filter { _.nonEmpty}
  .flatMap(line => JsonMethods.parse(line).toOption)
  .map(_.extract[BusModel])

class CustomProcess() extends ProcessWindowFunction[BusModel, BusModel, String, TimeWindow] {
  lazy val busState: ValueState[BusModel] = getRuntimeContext.getState(
    new ValueStateDescriptor[BusModel]("BusModel state", classOf[BusModel])
  )

  override def process(key: String, context: Context, elements: Iterable[BusModel], out: Collector[BusModel]): Unit = {
    for (e <- elements) {
      if (busState.value() != null) {
        out.collect(busState.value())
        val result: Double = calculateSomething(e, busState.value())
      }
      busState.update(e)
      println(s"BusState: ${busState.value()}")
    }
  }
}

val dataStream: DataStream[BusModel] = busDataStream
  .keyBy(_.VehicleNumber)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10))
  .process(new CustomCountProc)
```

After the new information is prepared, I would like this data to be put into the Cassandra database. I tried to implement this value using a connector, but unfortunately the new records don't show up in the database ...

I also added a createTypeInformation method which should map the data of the selected object to the column types in the database, but that unfortunately didn't help.

```
createTypeInformation[(String, Double, Double, Double)]
val sinkStream = dataStream
  .map(busRide => (
    java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString,
    busRide.valueA,
    busRide.valueB,
    busRide.valueC,
  ))

CassandraSink.addSink(sinkStream)
  .setQuery("INSERT INTO transport.bus_flink_speed(" +
    "\"FirstColumn\", " +
    "\"SecondColumn " +
    "\"ThirdColumn\", " +
    "\"ForthColumn\")" +
    " values (?, ?, ?, ?);")
  .setHost("localhost")
  .build()

env.execute("Flink Kafka Example")
```

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Do You have any logs from that jobs? Any exceptions? Does the data reach the `ProcessFunction` ?

Comment: Are you sure than sinkStream is reading values ?